# Windows 10 IoT Core can't run any application

Tags: windows-iot

I am using a fresh installation of Windows 10 IoT Core build 10.0.10586 on my Raspberry Pi 2 Model B.

Everytime I want to start an application (headed or headless) from the web interface, I only get the error from the following picture.

[image]

No matter what kind of application I chose.

When I try remove an application via PowerShell or set it on the startup list, I get error like this:

[image]

I have no clue what i can do to solve this. Out of VS2015 Community it works perfectly.

Comment: We need more information

Comment: I install the applications/tasks via VS. But neither my applications nor the preinstalled ones can be started, deleted, or set as startup. I really don't know what more information i can give. I know it's not that much.. I have tested the instructions by Microsoft and many others i found on google. But I don't know what to look for now.

Comment: I mean, event logs or system logs on the Pi ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a supported SD Card to hold your operating system?  I was using a Class 10 card and I had occasional boot problems and some locking up.  Perhaps a different SD Card would solve your problem.

Make sure it's class 10.  The following have worked well for me:

Samsung 32GB EVO Class 10 Micro SDHC
or
SanDisk Ultra Micro SDHC

Comment: 32 gb or less, except on a 3b+.